# java-linked list sublist method

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, sublist

I am attempting to write a subList method, which returns a list consisting of the current object list inclusively between indexes `fromIndex` and `toIndex`.

For example, if I had list consisting of

> 9 11 20 23 28 30

and I called `subList(1,4)`, I should get a new list of

> 11 20 23 28

returned.

For my subList() method, I tried running it but I end up entering an infinite loop. When the next node is empty, it is supposed to exit the loop but that is not happening so I need help figuring out why this infinite loop is happening and what I can do about it. Any help is appreciated!

```
private class Node<N extends Comparable<N>> {
    private N data;
    private Node<N> next;
}

private Node<L> head;

public List() {
    head = null;
}   

private void add(Node<L> node) {
        if(head == null) {
            head=node;
        } else {
            getFinal().next = node;
        }
    }

public Node<L> getFinal(){
    Node<L> node = head;
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
    }
    return node;
}

public int size() {
    if (head == null) return 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (Node<L> curr = head; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
        counter++;
    return counter;
}

public List<L> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex > size()-1 || toIndex < 0 || toIndex > size()-1) { 
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    List<L> n = new List<L>();
    Node<L> startNode = head;
    int counter = 0;
    while(startNode != null) {
        if(counter >= fromIndex && counter <= toIndex) { //infinite loop happens here
            n.add(startNode);
        }
        startNode=startNode.next;
        counter++;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing a class declaration, some methods are not inside a class.

Comment: You don't show the code where you create and assign values to your list. Are you sure you're not adding a node to the list which already has it's `next` field set to something else in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a new node, rather than adding nodes of the original list to a new list (i.e. the sublist):

```
while(startNode!=null){
   if(counter>=fromIndex && counter<=toIndex){ //infinite loop happens here
       Node<L> nl = new Node<L>();
       nl.data = startNode.data;
       n.add(nl);
    }
    startNode=startNode.next;
    counter++;
}
```

Otherwise, this will happen. Say you have the following list:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null
```

Now, say you call `subList(1, 2)`.This will call `n.add(2)`. This will call `getFinal()`, but `getFinal()` will still return 3 (and not 2), since 2.next is still pointing to 3.
So you add *after 3* and get an infinite cycle, because 2.next = 3:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2
     ^         ^ <-- Cycle in your list...
```

Answer (score 0):

If we just look at your subList method's while loop, your exit condition doesn't make sense. You have:

```
while(startNode != null) {
    if(counter >= fromIndex && counter <= toIndex) { //infinite loop happens here
        n.add(startNode);
    }
    startNode=startNode.next;
    counter++;
}
```

You should have:

```
while(startNode != null && counter <= toIndex) {
    if(counter >= fromIndex) {
        n.add(startNode);
    }
    startNode=startNode.next;
    counter++;
}
```

In a nutshell you are saying: loop until either there are no more non-null nodes OR until we are passed the toIndex. Not only is that solution more efficient since the algorithm will short circuit when toIndex has been reached an not bother processing a bunch of additional Nodes that would never possibly be part of your result set, but also in the case where you have cycles in your list, you wouldn't run into an infinite loop.

Comment: as an aside, for completeness it is also good idea to throw an exception if toIndex < fromIndex.